# Adding vertex set distance from first or last vertex in polyline using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, line, vertices

For ArcMap 10.1, is there a tool that will add only one vertex (node) a set distance from the first vertex, or alternatively, a set distance from the last vertex for multiple polylines?

The original vertices need to be retained for each polyline.

I have over 500 polylines and creating vertices individually in an edit session is taking forever!

Comment: Would [Densify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) help?  It will add vertices every `x` units, but I don't think it'll stop at just one so may not entirely suit your needs.  **Note** this modifies your data, it doesn't create a separate output

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking instead of "extending" the line to add another vertex/endpoint. I think a picture will make your question clearer.

Comment: Only need to add a vertex within a polyline, not extend it or change its length.

Comment: How do you decide whether to place the vertex that set distance from the start vs the end or are you wanting both?  Please keep clarifying via an [edit] to your question because potential answerers do not always have time to read comment trails.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a copy of your lines
2. Run add geometry attributes on it, part count and length
3. Select ones with length > limit and part_Count=1
4. Open table, select field Shape, pick field calculator, parser Python, advanced

Use expression below:

```
def insertV(dist,shp):
 newP=shp.positionAlongLine (dist).firstPoint
 n,arr,part=0,arcpy.Array(),shp.getPart(0)
 m=len(part)
 for i in range(m):
  p=part.getObject(i); L=shp.measureOnLine(p)
  if L>dist:
   n+=1
   if n==1:arr.add(newP)
  arr.add(p)
 return arcpy.Polyline(arr)
```

## ---------------------------

```
insertV(100, !Shape! )
```