# Insert x number of vertices on a Polyline with field calculator or Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, field-calculator

I've seen [Adding vertex set distance from first or last vertex in polyline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210809) which is similar to what I am trying to do, except instead of inserting one vertex a distance from the start point and all, I would like to retain existing vertices, but add x number of vertices to the line as a whole.

```
 def insertV(dist,shp):
 newP=shp.positionAlongLine (dist).firstPoint
 n,arr,part=0,arcpy.Array(),shp.getPart(0)
 m=len(part)
 for i in range(m):
  p=part.getObject(i); L=shp.measureOnLine(p)
  if L>dist:
   n+=1
   if n==1:arr.add(newP)
  arr.add(p)
 return arcpy.Polyline(arr)
---------------------------
insertV(100, !Shape! )
```

I imagine what I would need it to do is... say I need to add 5 vertices (this number would be stored in a field so it could be used as a variable) to a line

Get the line length, divide the length by variable5 which would be the interval distance I could add a vertice at, and then proceed to add a vertice at that interval distance.

Something like this:

```
 def insertV(addVx,shp):
 intDist = shp.length / addVx  #Interval Distance = line length / a field called addVx with the number of vertices to add stored

 #code to retain existing vertices and add vertices at the interval distance

---------------------------
insertV(!addVx!, !Shape! )
```

Anyone know if it is possible to do this?

Comment: It's certainly possible, though should make sure the coordinate system is Cartesian and not geodesic.  Keep in mind that you'll need to scale the segment which is at the break point appropriately.  You don't really have *any* of that math in your code sample (and it's not formatted as valid Python, either).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using geopandas if this'll help. You can just change the `5` to whatever number of vertices you want to add in the `apply` statement at the bottom, and also I've added an assertion that the file is projected which would be easy enough to change with the `to_crs` method if need be.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString, Point

def add_vertices(linestring, num_verts=1):
    if type(linestring) == LineString:
        return insert_verts(linestring, num_verts)
    if type(linestring) == MultiLineString:
        return MultiLineString([insert_verts(line, num_verts)
                                for line in linestring.geoms])


def insert_verts(linestring, num_verts=1):
    dist = linestring.length / (num_verts + 1)
    coords = list(linestring.coords)
    data = [(linestring.project(Point(c)), c) for c in coords]
    existing = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["distance","xy"])
    inserts = [(dist * x, list(linestring.interpolate(dist * x).coords)[0])
               for x in range(1, num_verts+1)]
    new = pd.DataFrame(inserts, columns=["distance","xy"])
    return LineString(pd.concat([existing, new]).sort_values("distance").xy.tolist())


df = gpd.read_file("lines.shp")
assert df.crs.is_projected
df.geometry = df.geometry.apply(lambda x : add_vertices(x, num_verts=5))
df.to_file("lines_with_added_vertices.shp")
```

Comment: Oh wow, that looks promising!  I've been dealing with trying to install geopandas but had some issues at first. Got that sorted but now having issues running that code because the fiona module is not being found.  Thank you for that though, I will keep trying to figure out how to get things working on my end and let you know how that script works. Much appreciated